# How to prompt for a value in crystal reports, then override db field data if value entered? receiving number error on attempt

Tags: crystal-reports

I am modifying an existing crystal report that displays a `netamount` field from a database. I am trying to make it so the report prompts the user with an option to override the `netamount` result. If they do not fill out this prompt field, use the `netamount` from the DB.

I tried this and I don't get an error on the formula field. Also I do not get the prompt field to enter the override text. Not sure what I am missing.

I do get a number error when I try to run the report and it references my quotes in the IF statement.

- First I made a new Edit Parameter called `netammount_override`.
- Second I made a formula named `select_netamount`:

  ```
  IF {?netamount_override} >""
  THEN {DBTABLENAME.NETAMOUNT}
  ELSE {?netamount_override}
  ```
- Third I placed the formula on the report page.

Not sure why I don't get this item to show up on the prompt screen. I do get a number error though when running the report. The field is a number. I made sure that formula workshop says default values for nulls also.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Report uses the `HasValue()` function to test for a value of a parameter or field.  So you could rewrite your formula as:

```
IF HasValue({?netamount_override})
THEN {?netamount_override}
ELSE {DBTABLENAME.NETAMOUNT}
```

This will allow your formula to check if your optional parameter field has a value and determine whether to use the database field or the parameter based upon the result.

Any attempt to use an optional parameter that has not been assigned a value outside of the `HasValue()` function will usually result in an error message of "The parameter has no value", and I suspect this was the error you were receiving.

Comment: Thank you very much! that solved the error and makes sense. Now i have a new problem. The enter values page/parameter screen is requiring a value for that parameter of netammount_override.  As if i am missing a setting that says it doesn't require a value.

Comment: whoops never mind. i didnt have "optional prompt" selected. i do now and it works fantastic! thank you soo much for your help